# Rails view to list users in a zebra-striped table

Tags: ruby, html, ruby-on-rails

```
<% i = 0 %> 
<% @patients.each do |patient| %> 
 <tr class="<%= i % 2 == 0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd' %>">
    <td><%= link_to patient.id, patient %></td>
    <td><%= patient.user.username %></td>
    <td><%= patient.user.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= patient.user.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= patient.user.email %></td>
    <td><%= patient.user.active %></td>
    <td><%= patient.user.disabled %></td>
    <td>
      <ul class="Horizlist">
        <li><%= link_to 'Detail', patient %></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% i += 1 %>
```

I don't like that I have to define an i variable, is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails has a built in method, [`cycle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle), which will cycle between two more more options for you, so you don't have to manage the "Even"/"Odd" selection.

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <%= content_tag :tr, :class => cycle('Even', 'Odd') do %>
    <%= content_tag :td, link_to(patient.id, patient) %>
    <% [:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :active, :disabled].each do |property| %>
      <%= content_tag :td, patient.user.send(property) %>
    <% end %>
    <td>
      <ul class="Horizlist">
        <%= content_tag :li, link_to('Detail', patient) %>
      </ul>
    </td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you happen to use Haml, it looks quite nice. :)

```
- @patients.each do |patient|
  %tr{:class => cycle('Even', 'Odd')}
    %td= link_to(patient.id, patient)
    - [:username, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :active, :disabled].each do |property|
      %td= patient.user.send(property)
    %td
      %ul.Horizlist
        %li= link_to('Detail', patient)
```

Comment: Damn, how did I not know that? This is of course better than defining your own helper. +1

Comment: Also, if this is just for styling purposes: [you can do that with CSS without `class`es](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

Answer (score 3):

First of all ruby has an `each_with_index` method, so you can do `@patients.each_with_index do |patient, i|` instead of keeping a counter manually.

However with the conditional inside the loop that is still too much logic for the view in my opinion. What I'd do is define a helper for this, which might look like this:

```
# For each item in the given collection, yield that item and embed the
# result in the given tag. The class attribute of that tag alternates
# between class1 and class2
def alternating(collection, tag, class1, class2, html => {})
  collection.each_with_index do |item, i|
    html[:class] = i % 2 == 0 ? class1 : class2
    content_tag(tag, html, false) do
      yield item
    end
  end
end
```

And then call it like this:

```
<% alternating(@patients, :tr, 'Even', 'Odd') do |patient| %> 
  <td><%= link_to patient.id, patient %></td>
  <td><%= patient.user.username %></td>
  <td><%= patient.user.first_name %></td>
  <td><%= patient.user.last_name %></td>
  <td><%= patient.user.email %></td>
  <td><%= patient.user.active %></td>
  <td><%= patient.user.disabled %></td>
  <td>
    <ul class="Horizlist">
      <li><%= link_to 'Detail', patient %></li>
    </ul>
  </td>
<% end %>
```